# Count repeated group values in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I have a table with repeated records of individuals who have unique p_id who are member of different sites which have s_id. How can I get number of sites with X number of unique p_id?

So currently I have

```
p_id  name   s_id
----  ----   ----
1     John   01
2     Alex   01
3     Ben    02
4     Mark   02
5     Colin  02
etc
```

and I would like to use SQL to produce this table:

```
Site with 1 people: 0
Sites with 2 people: 1
Sites with 3 people: 3
```

I thought of doing this:

```
select p_id, s_id, s_count from 
  (select p_id, s_id, count(*) as s_count from mytable group by s_id)
```

but I don't think it's correct and there might be a better way - any ideas?

In case anyone is confused - I am looking for the sql statement to get the count, not anything else.

Comment: you'll never get that `site with 1 people: 0` from just this one table. a database cannot produce result rows out of thin air like that.

Comment: @MarcB - I know, obviously. But I want to get the count.

Comment: Actually, SQLite could generate numbers with a recursive CTE. But it isn't clear which database is actually wanted …

Comment: @CL - it is sqlite actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, count the number of people per site:

```
SELECT s_id,
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPeople
FROM ATable
GROUP BY s_id
```

This outputs one row per site.

Then, group again, but by the previously computed count column:

```
SELECT NumberOfPeople,
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfSites
FROM (SELECT s_id,
             COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPeople
      FROM ATable
      GROUP BY s_id)
GROUP BY NumberOfPeople
```